# Create Note with Userid firebase android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello guys in this application i use firebase as backend where i have created users with firebase auth. i want to Add the firebase Auth id in the note so i can retrive notes to that current logged in user. right now my notes gets added into database under (ToDo) however they get their own id and not the user id how can i fix this ?

```
    public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private Button  logout;
    private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
    private RecyclerView modelNotesList; //https://camposha.info/android-firebase-realtime-database-with-recyclerview/
    private FloatingActionButton addNotePageButton;
    private DatabaseReference notesDbRef;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;

    private TextView Title,text;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        Title = findViewById(R.id.tvNoteTitle);
        text = findViewById(R.id.TvNoteText);
        addNotePageButton = findViewById(R.id.fab_button_addPage);
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); // get inSTACE


        // acsess database and retrive data



        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("NoteList").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            NotesList notelist = dataSnapshot.getValue(NotesList.class);
            Title.setText( notelist.getTitle());
            text.setText(notelist.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,databaseError.getCode(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });











        addNotePageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //  Float button click
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, NoteInputActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }








    // everything below is used in the menu
    private void Logout(){ // sign out method called in switchcase
        firebaseAuth.signOut();
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { //create menu on toolbar
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu); //inflated inside
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) { // handle on click events on items on menu
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.logoutMenu:{
                Logout();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.ProfileMenu:{
                startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class));
                break;
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code pushes new `ToDoList` objects to `/toDo`.

So you can link a user to that `ToDoList` before using it with `setValue` using something similar to:

```java
ToDoList toDo = new ToDoList (notes,prio); // object of class ToDoList in models
toDo.setUserId(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
databaseReference.push().setValue(toDo)
```

Alternatively, you can nest the `ToDoList` objects under the user ID using:

```java
ToDoList toDo = new ToDoList (notes,prio); // object of class ToDoList in models
databaseReference.child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).push().setValue(toDo)
```

Note: Don't forget to handle cases where your active user is not logged in.

Comment: thanks this worked great... if i wanna read out the current logged in notes i go to user id then Todo then the note id ?

Comment: Depends which of the above you used. If you used the first, you would get all notes by that user using `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().ref('toDo').orderByChild('userId').equalTo(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addSingleValueEventListener(/* ... */)`. If you used the later, you could use `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().ref('toDo').child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addSingleValueEventListener(/* ... */)`.

Comment: i dont get any values i dont know why

Comment: When you say you are "getting no values", is `snapshot.hasChildren()` false? Also, you still haven't mentioned if you are using option 1 or 2

Comment: Hello thanks for the help by the way i redited the post with now (Displaying )  instead fo creating

Comment: right now when i start app without having any data to a specific user (notes) then the app crash when i remove that section of code which displays data and add note and then readd that part it doesnt crash but i cant see the notes so it seems like the connection work but i dont see the display.

Comment: Undo that edit and ask it as a separate question linking back to this one.

Comment: im using your nested version when i add data. i changed alot in the code all Todo is now called Note

Comment: i created this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59517555/android-studio-firebase-retrive-and-display-data     


diddnt know how to link it