# Android - Firebase RTDB retrieve and display data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I want to retrieve data but I don't see anything get displayed and at the same time my app crashes when I don't have data in my database so at least it seems the connection works. I'm also a beginner in Android Studio.

Note: This is a follow-up question from [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59495743/12528156).

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    Title = findViewById(R.id.tvNoteTitle);
    text = findViewById(R.id.TvNoteText);
    addNotePageButton = findViewById(R.id.fab_button_addPage);
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); // get inSTACE

    // acsess database and retrive data

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("NoteList").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        NotesList notelist = dataSnapshot.getValue(NotesList.class);
        Title.setText( notelist.getTitle());
        text.setText(notelist.getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,databaseError.getCode(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I wonder if all notes by a user will be displayed or only the first? I also wonder if I can add a delete button to every note without using view holders or anything else

Here is my XML for that view the relative layout

```xml
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvNoteTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:text="Title: "
    android:textSize="28dp"

    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TvNoteText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="356dp"
    android:text="Text: "
    android:textSize="22dp"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvNoteTitle"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.653" />
```

my database strucutre;:

[image: firebase database structure]

```
public class NotesList {

    private String title;
    private String text;

    public NotesList(){

    }

    public NotesList(String title, String text){

        this.title=title;
        this.text= text;

    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: No setter/field for -LxFfqThHtNWsk9bD5Zb

 No setter/field for -LxFfqThHtNWsk9bD5Zb  seems to be my problem thats my id for my posts on the specific user so thats works but i have setters in my class?

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot and the content of your `NotesList` class.

Comment: i added it in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You posted these error messages in a comment:

> No setter/field for -LxFfqThHtNWsk9bD5Zb
>
> No setter/field for -LxFfqThHtNWsk9bD5Zb

This typically means that you're trying to parse the wrong level in your JSON data. You're trying to parse a node that has children `-LxFfqThHtNWsk9bD5Zb` and `-LxFfqThHtNWsk9bD5Zb` into an object that doesn't have properties with that name.

Most likely you have a **list** of notes for each user under `/NoteList/$uid`, which means you also need to handle that list in your `onDataChange` by iterating over the children of the snapshot you get. Something like this should do the trick:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("NoteList").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot noteSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      System.out.println("Reading note from "+noteSnapshot.getKey());

      NotesList notelist = noteSnapshot.getValue(NotesList.class);

      System.out.println(notelist);
    }
  }
  ...
```

If you run this, you can see that it loads the notes from your database.

---

To display a list of notes in the app, you'll want to use a Recycler View. But I highly recommend reading a [tutorial on how to do that](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview), rather than repeat that here. Alternatively, you can use the adapters in [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) to populate your recycler view, rather than building your own adapter.

With your current code and layout you can set a single note's title and text into the UI with:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("NoteList").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot noteSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      System.out.println("Reading note from "+noteSnapshot.getKey());

      NotesList notelist = noteSnapshot.getValue(NotesList.class);

      Title.setText(notelist.getTitle());
      text.setText(notelist.getText());
    }
  }
  ...
```

Comment: I/System.out: Reading note from -LxFfo5HuRPQsBUSiFuc
I/System.out: com.example.examapplikation.Models.NotesList@993e940
    Reading note from -LxFfqThHtNWsk9bD5Zb
I/System.out: com.example.examapplikation.Models.NotesList@c8c0079

i get this but still nothing displayed

Comment: i have added a link of my database strucutre

Comment: or right now it doesnt seem  i bind them to my xml?

Comment: I added an explanation of that. But I highly recommend checking out the links I gave in my question, as a lot of what you're asking is already better taught elsewhere in tutorials on recycler view (or other ways of showing lists of items in Android), and loading data from Firebase into a list/recycler view.

Comment: i misssed what u wrote before thanks im using recycler view now.

Comment: You can accept an answer to a question you posted after a certain period. The system will let you know when that is.

Answer (score 0):

Even I am a beginner Android developer so I think that you should have a separate activity whose instance should be called from this file.